# Bearer Token Validation In Micronaut

Tags: security, jwt, microservices, micronaut, bearer-token

I am writing a new microservice in micronaut which will accept the JWT(Bearer) token sent by user in request, validate that token is not expired and has all the required claims. If all these criteria's are met then mark the request authenticated or else fail the request. I will annotate the controllers with `@Secured(IS_AUTHENTICATED)`, if request is marked as authenticated as I expect then response will be returned.

I gone through the micronaut security documentation but the documentation talks about generating JWT token with username and password which is not my requirement, I could not found a good example of token validation. If you could point me to correct direction of how to validate token, like should I extend any existing validators, any configs I need to update etc

Comment: If I understand the question, I don't think you need to validate the token yourself to satisfy the requirements you described.  The security framework will do that for you.

Comment: Does https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-security/blob/ef312e95f4f9e08f3b742c22ae4f09beb2c48076/security-jwt/src/main/java/io/micronaut/security/token/jwt/validator/JwtTokenValidator.java do what you want?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I saw that class but could not find any example that shows how to use it

Comment: "I saw that class but could not find any example that shows how to use it" - It isn't clear to me why you want to interact with it directly but it is a bean in the context so you could inject it wherever you like and from there you can invoke the `validateToken` method at https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-security/blob/ef312e95f4f9e08f3b742c22ae4f09beb2c48076/security-jwt/src/main/java/io/micronaut/security/token/jwt/validator/JwtTokenValidator.java#L77.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown: I was kinda going in wrong direction. https://www.geeksbeginner.com/jwks-authentication-with-micronaut/ is what I was looking for. Thanks for your help

Comment: @SandeepKumar I am also trying to solve the same problem. Please if you can guide me through. I didn't get where are you doing custom validations of expiry and claims in above link

Comment: @navaljain: Micronaut does that for you. Follow the link I posted in my comment and you should be good.

Comment: @navaljain: Micronaut does that for you. Follow the link I posted in my comment above and you should be good.